# Making a Sylius plugin : No route found for "GET /admin/seller/"

Tags: symfony, sylius

I'm trying to define routing for entity seller administration in Sylius.
When I try to reach the page http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/sellers/, I've got those errors:

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: No route
> found for "GET /admin/sellers/"
>
> at
> /home/robomatix/www/html_local/Artaban/SyliusSimpleMarketplacePlugin/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php:139
> at
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener->onKernelRequest(object(GetResponseEvent),
> 'kernel.request', object(TraceableEventDispatcher))   at
> call_user_func(array(object(RouterListener), 'onKernelRequest'),
> object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request',
> object(TraceableEventDispatcher))
> (/home/robomatix/www/html_local/Artaban/SyliusSimpleMarketplacePlugin/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php:104)
> at
> Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener->__invoke(object(GetResponseEvent),
> 'kernel.request', object(ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
> (/home/robomatix/www/html_local/Artaban/SyliusSimpleMarketplacePlugin/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:212)
> at
> Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(array(object(WrappedListener),
> object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener),
> object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener),
> object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener),
> object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener),
> object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener),
> object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener),
> object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener),
> object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener)), 'kernel.request',
> object(GetResponseEvent))
> (/home/robomatix/www/html_local/Artaban/SyliusSimpleMarketplacePlugin/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:44)
> at
> Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request',
> object(GetResponseEvent))
> (/home/robomatix/www/html_local/Artaban/SyliusSimpleMarketplacePlugin/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php:139)
> at
> Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request',
> object(GetResponseEvent))
> (/home/robomatix/www/html_local/Artaban/SyliusSimpleMarketplacePlugin/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:129)
> at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request),
> 1)
> (/home/robomatix/www/html_local/Artaban/SyliusSimpleMarketplacePlugin/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:68)
> at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 1,
> true)
> (/home/robomatix/www/html_local/Artaban/SyliusSimpleMarketplacePlugin/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:202)
> at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
> (web/app_dev.php:16)   at require('/home/robomatix/www/html_local/Artaban/SyliusSimpleMarketplacePlugin/tests/Application/web/app_dev.php')
> (/home/robomatix/www/html_local/Artaban/SyliusSimpleMarketplacePlugin/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/WebServerBundle/Resources/router.php:42)

and

> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException:
>
> at
> /tmp/a99a18f5531c358fe4a7a5bc81471b03/cache/appDevDebugProjectContainerUrlMatcher.php:3988
> at appDevDebugProjectContainerUrlMatcher->match('/admin/sellers/')
> (/home/robomatix/www/html_local/Artaban/SyliusSimpleMarketplacePlugin/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Matcher/UrlMatcher.php:95)
> at
> Symfony\Component\Routing\Matcher\UrlMatcher->matchRequest(object(Request))
> (/home/robomatix/www/html_local/Artaban/SyliusSimpleMarketplacePlugin/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Router.php:262)
> at Symfony\Component\Routing\Router->matchRequest(object(Request))
> (/home/robomatix/www/html_local/Artaban/SyliusSimpleMarketplacePlugin/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php:109)
> at
> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener->onKernelRequest(object(GetResponseEvent),
> 'kernel.request', object(TraceableEventDispatcher))   at
> call_user_func(array(object(RouterListener), 'onKernelRequest'),
> object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request',
> object(TraceableEventDispatcher))
> (/home/robomatix/www/html_local/Artaban/SyliusSimpleMarketplacePlugin/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php:104)
> at
> Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener->__invoke(object(GetResponseEvent),
> 'kernel.request', object(ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
> (/home/robomatix/www/html_local/Artaban/SyliusSimpleMarketplacePlugin/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:212)
> at
> Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(array(object(WrappedListener),
> object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener),
> object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener),
> object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener),
> object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener),
> object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener),
> object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener),
> object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener),
> object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener)), 'kernel.request',
> object(GetResponseEvent))
> (/home/robomatix/www/html_local/Artaban/SyliusSimpleMarketplacePlugin/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:44)
> at
> Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request',
> object(GetResponseEvent))
> (/home/robomatix/www/html_local/Artaban/SyliusSimpleMarketplacePlugin/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php:139)
> at
> Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request',
> object(GetResponseEvent))
> (/home/robomatix/www/html_local/Artaban/SyliusSimpleMarketplacePlugin/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:129)
> at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request),
> 1)
> (/home/robomatix/www/html_local/Artaban/SyliusSimpleMarketplacePlugin/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php:68)
> at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 1,
> true)
> (/home/robomatix/www/html_local/Artaban/SyliusSimpleMarketplacePlugin/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:202)
> at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
> (web/app_dev.php:16)   at require('/home/robomatix/www/html_local/Artaban/SyliusSimpleMarketplacePlugin/tests/Application/web/app_dev.php')
> (/home/robomatix/www/html_local/Artaban/SyliusSimpleMarketplacePlugin/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/WebServerBundle/Resources/router.php:42)

Sorry, I couldn't use the implementation for code...

Here is my code:

Artaban/SyliusSimpleMarketplacePlugin/src/Resources/config/config.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: 
 "@ArtabanSyliusSimpleMarketplacePlugin/Resources/config/services.yml" 
}
- { resource: 
"@ArtabanSyliusSimpleMarketplacePlugin/Resources/config/resources.yml" 
}
- { resource: "@ArtabanSyliusSimpleMarketplacePlugin/Resources/config/grids/grids.yml" 
}
```

Artaban/SyliusSimpleMarketplacePlugin/src/Resources/config/resources.yml

```
sylius_resource:
    resources:
        app.seller:
            driver: doctrine/orm # You can use also different driver here
            classes:
                model: Artaban\SyliusSimpleMarketplacePlugin\Entity\ArtabanSimpleMarketplace_Seller
```

Artaban/SyliusSimpleMarketplacePlugin/src/Resources/config/grids/admin/seller.yml

```
 sylius_grid:
grids:
    app_admin_seller:
        driver:
            name: doctrine/orm
            options:
                class: Artaban\SyliusSimpleMarketplacePlugin\Entity\ArtabanSimpleMarketplace_Seller
        fields:
            name:
                type: string
                label: sylius.ui.name
            description:
                type: string
                label: sylius.ui.description
            enabled:
                type: twig
                label: sylius.ui.enabled
                options:
                    template: "@SyliusUi/Grid/Field/enabled.html.twig"
        actions:
            main:
                create:
                    type: create
            item:
                update:
                    type: update
                delete:
                    type: delete
```

Artaban/SyliusSimpleMarketplacePlugin/src/Resources/config/grids/grids.yml

```
imports:
- { resource: '@ArtabanSyliusSimpleMarketplacePlugin/Resources/config/grids/admin/seller.yml' }
```

Artaban/SyliusSimpleMarketplacePlugin/src/Resources/config/routing/admin/seller.yml

```
app_admin_seller:
resource: |
    alias: app.seller
    section: admin
    templates: SyliusAdminBundle:Crud
    redirect: update
    grid: app_admin_seller
    vars:
        all:
            subheader: app.ui.seller
        index:
            icon: 'file image outline'
type: sylius.resource
```

Artaban/SyliusSimpleMarketplacePlugin/src/Resources/config/routing/admin.yml

```
app_admin_seller:
resource: '@ArtabanSyliusSimpleMarketplacePlugin/Resources/config/routing/admin/seller.yml'
```

Artaban/SyliusSimpleMarketplacePlugin/src/Resources/config/routing.yml

```
app_admin:
resource: '@ArtabanSyliusSimpleMarketplacePlugin/Resources/config/routing/admin.yml'
prefix: /admin
```

How can I display a page "admin/sellers" from which I can CRUD sellers?

Answer (score 0):

From what you have posted, you didn't import `Artaban/SyliusSimpleMarketplacePlugin/src/Resources/config/routing/admin.yml` in `app/config/routing.yml` configuration.